bitcoin-cli getbalance command returning 0, but the wallet has funds
i'm trying to do some transactions using bitcoin-core and lightning on testnet, with bitcoincore lightning running connected to testnet when i load my wallet and use the getbalance command it returns 0, but when checking the wallet address on blockstream explorer it shows that there are funds to it, i'm wondering what can be wrong in this situation
i'm starting bitcoincore with "bitcoind -testnet" and lightning with "lightningd   --bitcoin-rpcuser=bitcoin   --bitcoin-rpcpassword=bitcoin   --bitcoin-rpcconnect=127.0.0.1   --bitcoin-rpcport=18332   --bitcoin-cli=/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli --testnet --conf=/home/user/lightning/lightning.conf" maybe the problem is here?
